# treat "\\n" as escape character in python

Tags: python, python-unicode, unicode-escapes

how can I print "\n" as a normal newLine "\n"

example:

> `str = "lorem\\nipsum"`

#### the output should be:

`lorem`
`ipsum`

#### not : `lorem\\nipsum`

### I tried :

> `print(str[6:])`

and more stuff but nothing work

#THE IDEA IS TO GET RAID OF ONLY ONE BACKSLASH TO PRINT IT AS NEWLINE CHARACTER AS SHOULD

> `ord("\x1c")`

> `>>28`

> `mystr = "\\x1c"`

> `ord(mystr[1:])`

````
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 3 found```



## here's the actual code ##
````

import string

lower = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
lower_dec = []

upper = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
upper_dec = []

nums = list(map(str,range(0,10)))
nums_dec =[]

def E(key,p):

```
cipherList = []
cipherText = []
for row in range(len(key)):
    c = 0
    for i in range(len(key[row])):
        c+= (ord(p[i])*key[row][i])%26
    cipherList.append(repr(chr(c)))


for char in cipherList:
    cipherText.append(char.replace("'",''))


return cipherText
```

key = [[2,3,5],[11,4,7],[20,12,12]]
p = ['p','a','y']

print(E(key,p))

#that prints ['\x1c', '1', '.']

Comment: Just use one backslash

Comment: `print(r"hello\nworld")` - prepending the string with `r` makes python interpret any character as raw string

Comment: Why do you have two backslashes? You seem to understand that escape sequences only need one?

Answer (score 1):

In python you can just do:

```
print("lorem\nipsum")
```

This will print:

```
lorem
ipsum
```

Python will automatically recognize that as an escape character. For the full list of escape characters please have a look at [this](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/escapes.html).

Comment: If you want keep the `\\n` you could do `print(str.replace("\\n", "\n"))` to have the desired output but I do not understand why you want that.

Comment: I'm training on cyphir algorith that when the algorithm change the char value ,it might give an escape character like the decimal value value 28 wich is "\x1c"

Comment: here is the code import string

lower = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
lower_dec = []

upper = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
upper_dec = []

nums = list(map(str,range(0,10)))
nums_dec =[]



def E(key,p):

 cipherList = []
 cipherText = []
 for row in range(len(key)):
  c = 0
  for i in range(len(key[row])):
   c+= (ord(p[i])*key[row][i])%26
  cipherList.append(repr(chr(c)))


 for char in cipherList:
  cipherText.append(char.replace("'",''))

 return cipherText






key = [[2,3,5],[11,4,7],[20,12,12]]
p = ['p','a','y']


print(E(key,p))

Comment: This is something that belongs in your original question. Please edit that.  But u can just replace that escape character (whatever it may be) with "\n" for the print statement.

Comment: it looks easy to solve but actually I do the search but nothing help .. I mean any where